# hook_menu() item never reached?

Tags: 7, hooks, routes, navigation

I have a module where hook_menu() was already used to process ajax calls, like this:

```
function bizaudit_menu() {
  return [
    'bizaudit/ajax' => [
      'page callback'     => '_bizaudit_ajax_handle',
      'access arguments'  => ['access content'],
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ],
    'bizaudit/autoexec' => [
      'page callback'     => '_bizaudit_autoexec_handle',
      'access arguments'  => ['access content'],
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ],
  ];
}
```

That works pretty well from times, then I just added another item, now to handle some precise route, like this:

```
function bizaudit_menu() {
  return [
    'bizaudit/ajax' => [
      'page callback'     => '_bizaudit_ajax_handle',
      'access arguments'  => ['access content'],
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ],
    'bizaudit/autoexec' => [
      'page callback'     => '_bizaudit_autoexec_handle',
      'access arguments'  => ['access content'],
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ],
    'navigate' => [
      'page callback'     => '_bizaudit_navigate_handle',
      'access arguments'  => ['access content'],
      'type'              => MENU_CALLBACK,
    ],
  ];
}
```

But this route seems to be never recognized!
To be sure I changed the callback function like this:

```
function _bizaudit_navigate_handle() {
  $query_params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  echo implode('<br>', print_r($query_params, true));
  exit;
}
```

Using this url `127.0.0.1/apim/navigate` should cause the query params to be printed (here empty, but no matter), and nothing else to happen.
Instead I get the normal content of the involved page displayed!
(I didn't omit to clear the cache)

Maybe I'm missing someting obvious?

Comment: Did you clear your cache? New items will not be picked up until you do.

Comment: @Jaypan Sure I did, as already stated in my question!

Comment: What do you mean by "Instead I get the normal content of the involved page displayed!" normally if you tried a path that didn't exist you'd get a 404 page. So do you have another page that already exists on the url /apim/navigate? If so that might be your problem. Or did you mean you are seeing the 404 page content

Comment: @Leigh Yes, a page "/apim/navigate" exists : it's a simple normal page, then it now needs some special process when it has some query params. It's why I want to intercept it using `hook_menu()`, where I would do some stuff before redirecting to the normal url (without the special query params). Would it be that `hook_menu()` never works if the stated item is a real page?

Comment: hook_menu is for defining your own page paths in code. It's not for hooking into the processing of a page that already exists. So you've got a conflict where you have 2 pages with the same url and the latter (the node/view page or whatever is it with the same url) is taking precedence over your bizaudit_menu definition. So your code created path is never triggered as Drupal has found another route for your "apim/navigate" path. It might be worth creating a new question explaining what you want to achieve and someone might be able to provide a solution to that

Comment: @Leigh Thanks a lot: now I understand. And I don't need more help: with your explanation I could work differently, simply choosing to use a totally unknow path. In the other hand, you could post a real response, so I would accept it. Thanks anew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem

hook_menu is for defining your own page paths in code. It's not for hooking into the processing of a page that already exists. So you've got a conflict where you have 2 pages with the same url and the latter (the node/view page or whatever is it with the same url) is taking precedence over your bizaudit_menu definition. So your code created path is never triggered as Drupal has found another route for your "apim/navigate" path